# Grafana: SQL Query: How to apply a filter only if it is selected

Tags: sql, grafana

I am using PostgreSQL Connection with Grafana.

I have the following SQL query:

```
select video_type as video, 
  sum(cv.duration)/3600 as "Duration (Hours)"
  from fact.content_view cv 
where  $__timeFilter(cv.datetime at time zone 'UTC+5')
  and cv.channel_id in ($channel)
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

When this query is executed by Grafana it is transformed to:

```
select video_type as video, 
  sum(cv.duration)/3600 as "Duration (Hours)"
  from fact.content_view cv 
where  cv.datetime at time zone 'UTC+5' BETWEEN '2021-12-30T17:14:09.53Z' AND '2022-01-06T17:14:09.53Z'
  and cv.channel_id in ('48','13002','1071','1076','310','309','19','13004','1073','815','806','824','823','624','52','670','186','827','14','191','687','13001','58','54','63','305','306','2','6','13005','896','10016','37','304','103','105','104','148','149','946','808','11011','31','192','268','224','269','283','294','183','11001','218','5','188','189','767','759','300','11020','11021','116','814','86','96','99','1049','690','231','204','213','13003','292','1051','46','156','1048','297','164','33','820','32','165','166','206','55','56','119','917','271','100','232','285','220','247','248','61','110','228','187','36','111','193','34','251','11027','244','246','245','117','1087','151','242','11037','163','197','1031','829','828','39','258','178','147','252','11028','10009','756','256','11024','9120','270','273','121','291','1050','290','948','198','721','159','185','51','24','10010','68','1074','124','11022','862','296','219','10011','870','16','114','298','1026','308','90','93','95','853','97','833','142','98','138','137','140','861','272','118','699','113','145','10012','696','10015','771','210','287','106','249','4','62','109','10005','154','11025','102','243','240','229','211','128','254','1033','157','10013','10003','1058','1078','1080','1077','1081','1079','1082','9147','1015','49','42','59','10002','259','683','208','295','71','859','11036','205','10018','265','241','335','908','10014','864','1072','1000','28','107','30','226','621','27','301','233','127','6666','-1','112','29','311','320','312','313','314','315','316','317','318','319','239','126','200','10008','238','184','253','108','160','282','11035','122','10006','278','279','280','281','20','209','65','1070','66','321','53','236','195','222','115','207','199','293','214','162','10007','123','11032','230','11030','181','10001','731','1034','286','216','302','793','212','217','38','132','158','790','791','792','263','950','284','826','227','1057','203','1092','1124','1131','7','1141','1157','1142','1143','1144','1145','1146','1147','1155','1156','1111','1132','1133','1134','1135','1136','1137','1138','1139','1140','1093','1110','1129','1112','1113','1114','1098','1099','1126','1101','1102','1088','1090','1117','1118','1130','1158','1105','1120','1121','1122','307','44','674','134','261','73','88','1107','1108','255','1020','1038','129','12','825','267','8','266','13','143','146','150','18','1028','72','75','69','171','84','25','170','169','43','35','40','21','94','11','10','74','80','67','257','41','76','173','85','87','262','182','179','174','177','152','77','153','172','260','168','180','176','83','47','45','89','26','81','9','70','91','78','92','175','82','23','10017','288','925','196','734','120','1022','201','235','1','131','11023','17','237','11031','130','1075','3','11033','1053','144','655','264','907','22','139','817','935','194','11002','722','215','12001','125','764','816','57','812','813','101','64','161','819','190','1027','11029','274','275','276','277','167','133','155','299','860','223','136','663','60','289','640','50','847','830','839','225','11034','768','625','202','1039','742','221','15','1055','303','79','818','1056','10004')
group by 1
order by 2 desc
```

The channel variable is defined in the following way:

```
select  channel_id __value, name __text  from dimension.channel where name not like '\_%' order by 2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5IwI.png)

My problem is that when 'all' is selected in the 'channel' filter, then Grafana passes all 'channel ids' to the SQL query. And in case I have more than 5000-6000 ids, those are cut by Grafana. Thus I got incorrect result.

So I am trying somehow, in case there are no values selected from the filter then the whole filter to be skipped. Only in case certain values are selected then this filtered to be applied. Ideally I should be able to limit the selection by e.g. 10-20 values from the filter. Unfortunately, I cannot make that work. Other suggestion to overcome the problem are welcomed as well.

Thanks

Comment: you should to be more specific what kind of SQL DB are you using

Comment: Thanks, it's PostgreSQL DB

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution to the problem:

1. In the filter, for the 'All' value I configured '-99'
2. I changed the 'where' clause in the following way:

```
      and (-99 in ($channel) OR cv.channel_id in ($channel))
```

3. The 'All' is selected it is evaluated to:

```
      and (-99 in (-99) OR va.channel_id in (-99))
```

Here the first part of the 'OR' condition is 'true'

4. When some something else is selected it it evaluated to e.g.

```
     and (-99 in ('48','13002') OR va.channel_id in ('48','13002'))
```

Here the first part of the 'OR' condition is false, so it the second part is calculated.

The the downside of this approach is that in case you want to select many values, the query becomes even larger as the values are doubled. But in case 'All' is selected it works very well also from performance perspective is much better.

Comment: Very nice trick. A more readable solution would be to have `(${channel:csv} IS NULL OR va.channel in ${channel})` and then set the "all" value to "null"

Answer (score 0):

The idea `How to apply a filter only if it is selected` is wrong. You need to change t to: how to write query condition, which will select all record with `Custom all value`.

One possible solution is to configure `Custom all value` settings for `channel` variable to `%`.

Then query condition will be (`~` is case sensitive matching):

```
AND cv.channel_id ~ '${channel:pipe}'
```

When `All` channel variable is selected then this SQL will be generated/executed:

```
AND cv.channel_id ~ '%'
```

which should match all records (not tested, so final condition may still need some tweaks).

Comment: This does not work - seems invalid SQL syntax.

Comment: @YouriKalinov as I said: I gave you idea (not a copy&paste solution - you will be very optimistic that someone will spend a hour to replicate exactly your use case and you will copy paste that ready solution in one second) - that still need some tweaking!

Answer (score 0):

If you using AlphaNumeric values in your variable you can use like below after changing `Custom all value` option to `'All'` in your variable (If you use 0 then you will get convert error after selection varchar values).

*(I have Environment, InstanceName, DatabaseName variables. I use Multi-value and Include All options for DatabaseName variable and I set `Custom all value` = `'All'` for my DatabaseName variable.)*

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Connections]
WHERE $__timeFilter([TimeStamp])
    AND [Environment] = ${Environment:sqlstring}
    AND [InstanceName] = ${InstanceName:sqlstring}
    AND ('All' IN ($DatabaseName) OR [DatabaseName] IN ($DatabaseName))
```

`'All' = ${DatabaseName:singlequote}` usage also correct but it will be failed when multiple value selected. So, `'All' IN ($DatabaseName)` usage better for all.